# Why can I not access the internet when Windows 7 finds no issue with the ethernet connection and the network can see my device?

Tags: windows-7, networking, lan

So I just moved from a house to an apartment. In the house and the apartment I had Uverse set up - and in both I had my desktop connected via a ~40 foot long cat5 cable. However, upon moving to the apartment I found that my ethernet connection no longer provides internet. This would seem like a mundane problem if not for:

1. The router can see the computer on the network
2. Windows 7 (the desktop's OS) detects *no problems* with the ethernet connection.
3. Connections over the internet (i.e. browser windows, Pandora, etc.) do not immediately fail. Instead they load for 2 minutes and then finally give up.
4. Devices connected over the Wifi (PS4, Laptop) access the internet just fine

While removing the cat5 cable from my house, I accidentally damaged the locking tab but managed to bend it back into the appropriate position. I would suspect that a bad cat5 cable might be to blame if not for the above issues (thought I've heard bad cat5 cables cause the most nonsensical problems) and the fact that I tested the cat5 cable by having it share internet between my laptop (working internet) to my desktop and it functioned just fine and provided the desktop with internet.

My ipconfig /all successfully finds a default gateway, DHCP server, and DNS server.

What could possibly be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was in fact one more thing to add to the list of "Crazy mysteries caused by damaged ethernet cables." I replaced the cable and it worked just fine. Hope this helps someone out (by, perhaps, teaching them to always blame the cables.)